# Allow non filled fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a model for an ASP.NET MVC view containing several properties:

- Subject
- Message
- Id

While subject and message are required, Id isn't required (it's hidden and only set
for an existing entry). Unfortunately, MVC validates it as required ( The If field 
is required) even though I haven't set the Required attribute.

Has someone a solution? Haven't found a solution here, maybe just searching wrong...

Kind regards,
Sascha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Id` is an `Int`... you can try making it `Int?` (nullable Int).
If it is nullabe, I think MVC will not validate it.

Another way, would be place a default value in that hidden, lets say a "-1"... and on the controller you can check it.

Comment: If you make it nullable it doesn't check.

Answer (score 1):

By default, ASP.Net Mvc will treat non-nullable properties as 'required' - even if you do not add the `[Required]` attrtibute to the property.  If your id is of type `int` - it is not-nullable and therefore required.

You have basically two options:

1. Change your Id property to `int?` - ie a nullable int.
2. Change the default setting for MVC to not regard non-nullable attributes as required.

Option 1 is straight-forward.  For option 2 add the following to the Application_Start method in your  global.asax

`DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = true;`